# Spring - Use/Load context file from jar file

Tags: java, spring, jboss5.x

I would like to load a context file from a jar file.  For example, I want to create a data access jar file - holds entity and dao objects and it would have a spring context file:  dataaccess-context.xml.

Now in my Web application I want to be able to access this jar using the context file.

I have placed the following in my web.xml:

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>
    classpath:com/vsg/dataccess/framework/context/dataaccess-context.xml
  </param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

When I do this I get a file not found exception.  The jar file is placed into the WEB-INF/lib directory.

Now running from with in Eclipse using JBoss I placed the spring jar files into the class path this did not solve the issue.

Any direction, I have read several links and so forth here and google and it all seems to be possible so not sure what I am doing incorrect here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible and it should be working for you.

Maybe is just some error in your configuration file. Try this:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        classpath:/com/vsg/dataccess/framework/context/dataaccess-context.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

See that the path starts with a slash.

Comment: Did a complete clean of the environment and using the above suggestion it all works now